# What is the action (command) to show all open windows in Debian?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE and would like to have a button to show all open windows. However I don't know what I should put as "Action" to get that it working. So how can I implement this? Is there a command for this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You mean "maximize" all windows that were previously minimized (iconified)? Or see all open windows displayed as reduced tiles that do not overlap? Or something else?

Comment: See all open windows displayed as reduced tiles that do not overlap. So that I can click on the one I'd like to skip to.

Comment: As far as I remember, using Alt+Tab showed the open windows as thumbnails if configured correctly. This was on KDE Plasma 4.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default action to show present windows is

**ctrl+F9**

This will zoom out and show all open windows.

**Alternatively**

If you go to

> System settings - Desktop behavior - Screen edges

You can set

> present windows (all desktops/current desktop/current application)

On one of the 8 screen edge actions, that way you just push your mouse cursor to whichever edge you created the action for, and it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thank you ctrl+F9 was the shortcut I was looking for. However instead of just the keyboard-shortcut I need an action/command that I can assign to a button to execute this.

Comment: Okay so I had to install xautomation (for xte) and the action/command I was looking for seems to be `"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key F9' 'keyup Control_L'"`. It's not fully working but maybe I'll fix the problems later. The shortcut can be found under Global Keyboard Shortcuts -> KWin -> **Toggle Present Windows (Current desktop)**.

Comment: Got it working via this command: `"sleep 0.2 && xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key F9' 'keyup Control_L'"` for xbindkeys.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this seems like a KDE issue. In the KDE docs there are few shortcuts already defined see. 
[docs.kde.org](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html)
maybe **ctrl+F10** or **ctrl+F9**. If one of those doesn't suit then you can probably look through the KDE docs to find the action you want.